# How to create a simple Calendar view with swipe gestures in Android

Tags: android, calendar

I am in the process of developing a simple Calendar, but I am not sure how to design the calendar view with the following swipe gestures:

- Left/Right to change month, and
- Up/Down to change year.

Can anyone show me an example or some pointers?

Really thanks for yours help !

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this article http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html and this one
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: Could you give me any example code about Calendar and swipe for more clear?